What is the Bike Speed vs. Wind Speed Equation?
I am generating a spreadsheet for triathlon bikers going to the 70.3 Half-Iron Man in Waco, TX and I want to calculate the time delay/save that two wind types cause: wind assistance (tailwind, $x>0$) and wind resistance (headwind, $x\leq 0$). I can't find an accurate equation for both cases based on the biker's best velocity $V_b$, air density $\rho$, area of the biker $A$, and coefficient of drag $C_D$.
The drag force is, $$F= C_D A \rho \frac{x^2}{2}$$
for some relative air speed, $x$.
The equation for bike speed, $V(x)$, that I find physically reasonable is a piecewise function for an unknown decay factor, $0<k\leq 1$:
$$V(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix} \sqrt{\left(\left(\frac{1}{k}+1\right)V_{b}\right)^{2}+x^{2}} -\frac{V_{b}}{k} & , \text{if}\:\: x>0 \\ V_{b}e^{kx} & , \text{if}\:\: x\leq 0 \end{matrix}\right.$$
where the first is hyperbolic and transitions to a linear relationship for large $x$, and the second is an exponential decay. At $x=0$, $V(0)=V_b$ for both cases.
Is there a better equation for $V(x)$ with this boundary condition?


About ten years ago, I wrote some computer code to do something like this.  Unless the course is dead flat, you will want to account for elevation change too, because it will have significant effects on your results.
The approach I used was to approximate power output based on the course profile and known average power output (the observation being that people tend to put out more power on uphills but can't on downhills; the average over an entire course is surprisingly consistent.)
Once you know (or estimate) what power the cyclist puts out at each time or distance segment, you can calculate the velocity/elapsed time over that segment. $P = F * v$ where $F$ is your drag force.  You can also include components of drag proportional to $v$ ("rolling resistance") depending on how technical you want to get.
This also requires estimating a rider Cd and other details, based on available data.
With a little bit of results analysis, you can estimate parameters and dial in a pretty good estimate for any individual rider.
A good reference for this is "Bicycling Science" by David Gordon Wilson.

Just reading through the book, it has great data on rolling resistance, though my spreadsheet already has roll resistance, grade resistance, and drive chain efficiency. I considered power being used in "k" as "air power" divided by "total power" exerted on the bike so it could be small and dimensionless, but I'm not 100% sure if its correct.

If you want a copy of my MATLAB code I'm happy to share.  Send me an email at msg5_at_cornell_dot_edu.
